# Using Graphs and DFS/BFS to Solve Relationship Problem

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, depth-first-search

[image]

I am having some issue approaching this question from a implementation perspective:

Let's say we are given two events people are attending. We want to see if any two people compared are attending the same event or different event. If there is more than one possibility, there may not be enough information to say. We have a list of three types of information: 'different_connection', 'sane_connection', and 'find_connection'. We want to determine the relationship between any two people in regards as to whether they attend either the same or different event. Or if there is not enough information to determine, it is unknown connection. Here is a sample input where each input is in the format of information type and two people being compared given a unique number:

```
find_connections(
    ['different_connection 3 5',
     'same_connection 5 6',
     'different_connection 1 2',
     'same_connection 2 5',
     'different_connection 9 8'
     'find_connection 1 3',
     'find_connection 1 5',
     'find_connection 2 5',
     'find_connection 6 8'])
```

And here is the expected output:

```
['same_connection','different_connection','same_connection', 'unknown_connection']
```

The possible outputs are either 'same_connection', 'different_connection', and 'unknown_connection' and the outputs are only for the find_connection information from given input list.

The number of people is bounded finite and only two people are compared at a time.

My goal is to implement this in O(n) worst case time where n is the number of elements in the input information list given.

I know how to do this in O(n^2) worst case time using looping and Depth First Search with Adjacency Lists in the find_connection case.

I drew a graph of this and understand how to get the output based on the graph but to do it in O(n) time seems tough.

But how do I do this in O(n) time? I know graphs are helpful here but it's not really possible to do in O(n) time.

Just need some ideas here.

Comment: You may be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Comment: Why disjoint set?

Comment: From the first paragraph of the introduction: *"The last operation allows to find out efficiently if any two elements are in the same or different sets."* Sound familiar?

Comment: Even if that was the case, I want to know the relationship between two different nodes. Let me upload a graph to help visualize it.